# Uploading Leads to SF Professional Edition using REST API

Tags: api, rest

My company has a Professional Edition Salesforce instance.

We're capturing leads on our company website.

I have written a simple program that uploads sales leads using  the REST API. It works fine and I can see the leads in my own Salesforce instance.

When the program logs in to my company's Salesforce instance and tries to do anything it gets back "The REST API is not enabled for this organization" (API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG)

Is this something we can turn on ourselves? The help articles I'm reading talk about passing an AppExchange security review. I'm not selling my lead upload tool to anybody else. It's an internal tool that just enables our company to upload leads to our own Salesforce instance, or would if we could figure out how to enable it.

Is this going to be possible without a lot of pain, or should I just forget doing this via an API and instead just periodically email a CSV file out and have someone in sales manually import the leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to contact your "Account Executive", "Success Manager" or whatever is the title of Salesforce employee that takes care of your org. Probably you'll need to negotiate a fee to enable the API access. Or upgrade to Enterprise Edition. They can also enable it temporarily for data migrations but your use case suggests continuous load... Well, it never hurts to ask!

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005140&type=1

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BJmjIAG

Comment: We contacted them and they initially wanted to  charge double the amount per month, just to get this additional feature. However it proved possible to negotiate them down to a more reasonable amount.

Comment: Congratulations! Good to know.